# Set ``upload_to`` function of a field in a foreign key

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-file-upload

I have the following models structure:

```
class BaseMovie(models.Model):
    movie = models.FileField('Movie')
    width = models.IntegerField('Width')
    height = models.IntegerField('Height')
    duration = models.FloatField('Duration')

class SpecialMovie(models.model):
    base_movie = models.ForeignKey(BaseMovie, 'Base movie')
    # some other stuff
```

The idea behind is that I intend to use `BaseMovie` in several models.

My question is:

**How can I set, *in the `SpecialMovie` model*, the location to which the special movies will be uploaded?**

I think that storing only the metadata in the `BaseMovie` class and having the movie field with appropriate `upload_to` function in the `SpecialMovie` is not satisfying, because I would have to copy the code that fills the metadata in all the models with a foreign key to `BaseMovie`.

Comment: Heroku has a great article on uploading to Amazon S3: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`upload_to` can [be a callable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to); you could set it to a function that checks if the instance has a related SpecialMovie, and return the correct value accordingly.